# Rails - Find all projects of a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I started to learn Rails a few days ago and also have not much experience with Ruby too. The problem with me now is trying to find all the projects of a certain user, given the relationship below.

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects_users
    has_many :projects, :through => :projects_users
    attr_accessible :email, :firstname, :id, :lastname, :password, :username, :password
    has_secure_password
end
```

**Project Model**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects_users
    has_many :users, :through => :projects_users
    attr_accessible :date_created, :id, :name
end
```

**Project_User Model**

```
class ProjectsUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :user
end
```

My attempt so far is:

```
@projectuserid = ProjectsUsers.find(:all, :conditions => "user_id=#{session[:user_id]}")
@projects = Project.all(@projectuserid)
```

But it seems like `@projectuserid` is an array itself so the query doesn't work. I know it could be achieved in one line of code for this HABTM relationship model, but still I have so little knowledge about Rails.

Another approach of mine looks like this, but a blank result returned:

```
@projects = Project.find :all,
         :conditions => "id in (select distinct project_id from projects_users where user_id=#{session[:user_id]})"
```

Comment: Have you tried `u = User.find(session[:user_id]); u.projects` ?

Comment: The error is: uninitialized constant User::ProjectsUser

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is probably be due to the fact that you aren't following Rails' naming convention.

- Models should have names in singular form: `ProjectUser` rather than `ProjectsUsers`.
- If you aren't planning to save any additional data in the `ProjectUser` model, you'd be better off just using a normal `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation. In other words: no "join model", just a join table named `projects_users`.

So either you do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Or you do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :project_users
    has_many :projects, through: :project_users
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :project_users
    has_many :users, through: :project_users
end

class ProjectUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :project
end
```

In both cases you can do this: `user.projects` and `project.users`

Comment: That works hey ;) Just wonder when a user saves a project, do I need to take into account the join table since there is no project returned for the user that created it at the moment. The only thing that is saved in project controller ```def new``` is ```@project = Project.new```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that I understand what you mean, but if you want to connect the project to a user when it is created, you have to actively do that. For example like so: `@project.users << current_user`. Since rails needs id:s to create the join relation, I suspect you'd have to save the Project first, and then create the relation. Not sure about this though.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `@user.projects` to get all projects associated with a user.

Comment: The error is: uninitialized constant User::ProjectsUser

Comment: All the models look good. Have you tried tor restart your server and reset your database with `rake db:migrate:reset`?

Comment: Tried to restart the server, would it be something to do with routing?

Comment: Actually, i comletely agree with @jesper. Follow his advice. I didn't notice the naming you use but he's right. Here's the railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many describing how to organize many-to-many relationship.